# Does anything happen if you beat the high score in Rapunzel?

Tags: catherine

I'm currently finishing up all of the trophies (after finally beating all four Towers of Babel!), so I'm clearing all 128 stages of Rapunzel. I noticed that the high score for the "game" is around 218k (I think the high score increases throughout the course of the game, considering all the solution videos in [this video playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5775F9FDCBD08849) display a high score of 25500 and I recall seeing a high score around 60000 at one point, but the 218k score is displayed on the final night).

Based on how many stages I cleared in a row, it almost seems like I'd need to marathon all 64 stages of the game (there are two "versions" of the game, each with 64 stages) in order to beat it, but I don't want to do that if there's no reward for doing so. Do I get any sort of recognition or bonus content for beating the high score in Rapunzel? If there is, does it matter what high score I beat (25.5k vs 218k)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After painstakingly beating the high score (the 218k one), I can confirm that nothing special happens. 
The only thing that happens is that you are able to input your initials (or whatever 4 characters you want) for the machine to display on its high scores screen.

[image: new high score]

Naturally, beating the high score also changes the high score on the machine, but other than these things, you don't get anything for it.

---

On a side note, beating the high score of 218k did not require me to beat all 64 stages consecutively. I accidentally died on stage 33 (see high score 4) and continued from there, which got me the high score by almost 80k points.

Comment: That's brutal D:

Comment: @n_palum which, getting the high score or beating all those stages in general? :P

Comment: Both sound like a long painful afternoon :P